# Where has sysindex.rows gone?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

In SqlServer 2000, there used to be a table called sysindex which had a column rows.  This table is now:
-sys.indexes
-sys.partitions
-sys.allocation_units
-sys.dm_db_partition_stats

(see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx) but none of these tables contain the row columns?  So how do you find out how many rows there are for an index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is still there in the compatibility view `sys.sysindexes`.

You can also use

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id), SUM(rows)
FROM sys.partitions p 
WHERE index_id < 2 and OBJECTPROPERTYEX (object_id ,'IsUserTable' ) = 1
GROUP BY p.object_id
```

This should not be taken as in any way guaranteed accurate. It includes the effects of uncommitted transactions, forwarding pointers on a heap and can be manually updated with some undocumented parameters to [`UPDATE STATISTICS`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_nevarez/archive/2010/01/13/fooling-the-query-optimizer.aspx).